# Generating html linux documentation with sphinx

Tags: linux-kernel, python

I am trying to generate linux documentation from the `Documentation` folder. [This link](https://01.org/linuxgraphics/gfx-docs/drm/doc-guide/sphinx.html#sphinx-pre-install) suggests running `make htmldocs` in the `Documentation` folder, but whenever I try that, I get this error:

`Reading makefiles...
Updating goal targets....
 File 'htmldocs' does not exist.
Must remake target 'htmldocs'.
make: *** empty variable name.  Stop.
Makefile:68: recipe for target 'htmldocs' failed
make: *** [htmldocs] Error 2`

Any ideas how I can build the documentation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn’t run `make htmldocs` inside the `Documentation` directory; run it from the base kernel directory instead.

(This is true for the vast majority of kernel build commands: unless you specifically know otherwise, they should always be run from the base kernel directory, even when building sub-directories.)

Comment: Ok, this time I get this error `reST markup error:
/home/sarp/projects/eudyptula/linux/Documentation/driver-api/usb/typec.rst:215: (SEVERE/4) Unexpected section title or transition.` @StephenKitt. Any advice?

Comment: Hmm, the file was broken by [this commit](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/commit/?id=bdecb33af34f79cbfbb656661210f77c8b8b5b5f); you could revert it, the previous version of the `.rst` file has valid syntax.